# how to display from serialized array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
a:3:{ i:1; a:4:{
s:4:"time";s:1:"0";s:6:"points";s:1:"1";s:7:"correct";s:1:"1";
s:4:"data"; a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"0";} } i:2; a:4:{
s:4:"time";s:1:"0";s:6:"points";s:1:"0";s:7:"correct";s:1:"0";
s:4:"data"; a:1:{i:0;s:13:"kpk";} } s:4:"comp"; a:5:{
s:6:"points";s:1:"1";s:16:"correctQuestions";s:1:"1"; 
s:8:"quizTime";s:1:"9";s:6:"result";s:2:"50";s:4:"cats";
a:1:{i:0;s:2:"50";}} }
```

Hello everyone,
I have a problem with above serialized array.
I want to get the named 'data' array.
Could you please advaise me how to get this?

Comment: Use unserialize on the string

Comment: Just unserialize it (http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Hello...json_decode and unserialize method doen't work. When i tried with this functions, it shows NULL. Please.. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

```
$array=unserialize($serialized);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo'</pre>';
```

You can then access the information like a normal array. For more information see: [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: I get this array from database with this query function.
$userdata = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_sfwd-data', true)
   
and now i try to unserialize this.   
$array=unserialize($userdata);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo'</pre>';
    
 but it does not work. It shows nothing.

Comment: Please use var_dump($userdata) and show the output above.

Comment: Then $userdata does not deliver any result, I am not using Wordpress, so please ensure that your function call of "get_user_meta" is successful and provides data. If this is given, the unerialize will work out proper.

Comment: hello @D.Schalla,  $userdata works without unserialize function. When i print out the result without serialize, it shows the serialized array.The problem is 'unserialize'  i think.

Comment: Please use var_dump($userdata); directly under the $userdata=get_user_meta(...) and post the output. If this is false, it cannot work with unserialize. It should provide something different.

Comment: hi @D.Schalla, Now I got what i want. I'm confusing the serialized array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear this. :)